# Need to match running processes in egrep

Tags: linux, unix, ps, egrep

I need to find all running processes whose owner is neither root nor Student. I know how to not get running processes whose owner is neither root nor Student by type

```
ps aux | egrep '^[^(root)|(Student)]'
```

I am struggling with get all running processes that aren't Student or root. Right now, I only get some running processes by typing

```
ps aux | egrep '^[^(root)|(Student)]'
```

I tried `[a-z]+` and it shows root and other running processes. How to get all running process without root and Student using `egrep`?

Answer (score 1):

**`ps aux | grep -vE '^(root|Student) '`**

`'[^(root)|(Student)]'` would match letters which are not in the class, it's not what we want to achieve. Simply use `grep -E` (which is the same as `egrep`) with the regex `'^(root|Student) '` (match everything starting by either `root` or `Student` and ending in a space) but print everything *not* matching by using the `-v` option.

Also note `ps` lets you custom the columns. For example, if you only wanted the pids you could use `ps -eo ruser,pid` instead of `ps aux`. Or you could match by uid using `ruid` instead of `ruser` (specially handful if the user name gets truncated).